# Кашпо или не кашпо на картинке? Как называется предмет?

Tags: лексика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что изображено на картинке? Эта фигурная металлическая подставка является "кашпо" или неправомерно ее так называть? А то, что на ней, цветочные горшки и также никоим образом не "кашпо"?

Comment: Фигурная металлическая, насколько я понимаю, никак не кашпо, хотя я и не знаток...

Answer (score 1):

Такая металлическая конструкция обычно именуется *держателем* или *кронштейном* для кашпо:
https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/dlya-doma/predmety-interera/tsvety-vazy-kashpo/derzhateli-dlya-kashpo

Сами *кашпо* представляют собой декоративные (напр. керамические или фарфоровые)
сосуды для установки в них *горшков* с цветами; в комнатном варианте у них нет отверстий для стока воды (как в горшках). На фотографии в держателях обычные горшки.